# How do I make my bot leave a vc if no one joins the channel for 3 minutes in discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Here's my code for the leave command atm :

```py
    @commands.command(name='leave', aliases=['disconnect'])
    @commands.cooldown(1, 2, commands.BucketType.user)
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
    async def _leave(self, ctx: commands.Context):
          await ctx.voice_state.stop()
          del self.voice_states[ctx.guild.id]
```

Comment: `ctx.voice_client.disconnect()` will cause you to disconnect and leave the VC.

Comment: There is no such attribute `.voice_state.stop()` from `ctx` and deleting from `self.voice_states` will do nothing

Comment: I'm literally using it for my current music system and it disconnects perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're looking for a timeout after 3 minutes of nobody being in the vc, try this as a starting point:

```py
import asyncio

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
    if len(self.bot.get_guild(id).voice_client.channel.members) < 1:
        asyncio.sleep(180)
        if len(self.bot.get_guild(id).voice_client.channel.members) < 1:
            await self.bot.get_guild(id).voice_client.disconnect()
```

Comment: [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update)

Comment: Oh shit you're right, I'll revise my answer to use that, thank you!

Comment: Okay, I'll try this! Thanks!

Comment: @Pr0methium ah, i just noticed a typo, you need to add a colon after the second if statement, and after async def

Comment: lol its okay, I tried it already and even I noticed the typo xD

Comment: Oh also, I have a audio player task function so I tried implementing this in that func, its not working and its not showing any errors.

Comment: Oh well, unfortunately that won't work since listeners cant go in other functions, they only get triggered when the event occurs, if you just place it the same way you'd place a command or task, hopefully that'll work (Is this a multi-server bot? If so, A way to deal with that would be instead of a static id, put `member.guild.id` instead of a static id for get_guild)

Comment: Yes it is a multi-server bot, okay.

Comment: well I tried member.guild.id and but its giving me an Attribute Error : File "/home/runner/Music-1/Cogs/music.py", line 445, in on_voice_state_update
    if len(self.member.guild.id.voice_client.channel.members) < 1:
AttributeError: 'Music' object has no attribute 'member'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233288/discussion-between-pr0methium-and-alyx).